# Limit size of output file and create additional files if needed with Ruby

Tags: ruby, file, akamai

I have a script that outputs URLs based on input data. Each line of input generates roughly 20 URLs. This output is then used to upload to Akamai Content Control. However, Akamai has a limit on file size set to 50KB.

I know I can write a URL and then check file size. If file size breaks buffer, close that file and create a new one and repeat.

I am ultimately curious if there is a far more elegant way to handle this within Ruby with less overhead/code.

Thanks

Comment: Why not check the sum of the file size and the new line before writing?

Answer (score 0):

Before writing each line check if file size + line size is less then limit. Write to file or create new one accordingly.

```
index = 2; 
f = File.new('output_file.txt', 'w')
while(there_is_new_output_to_write) do #get new line
    if(f.size + output_line.size > LIMIT) do #if total size is too big
        Fileutils.cp('output_file.txt','output_file' + index + '.txt') #copy
        index = index + 1 #increment index for new file
        f = File.new('output_file.txt', 'w') #override output file
    end
    f.puts(output_line) #write new line
end
#here You will have index -1 files 
#that is if index is 4, then you will have output_file.txt, output_file2.txt, output_file3.txt, 
#but NOT output_file4.txt!
```

Alternatively if that is not a problem You can use some good archiving tool out there to splice files to 50kb size for You.

Comment: I've thought about seeing if I can use Ruby's Logger to create the file but it puts in a bunch of data. I just need a URLs, one per line.

Comment: Hope my answer clear how to handle file/file size in ruby now.